# save graphviz source to dot file using python

Tags: python, graphviz

I am writing a  visualisation with graphviz in python. I imported graphviz and pylab. I figured out how to save the graphic representation

```
import graphviz as gv
import pylab

g1 = gv.Graph(format='png')

g1.node('A')
g1.node('B')
g1.edge('A', 'B')

g1.view()
print(g1.source) 

filename = g1.render(filename='img/g1')

pylab.savefig('filename.png')
```

How can i save the source to a .dot file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you used `g1.render(filename='img/g1')`, it dumped the source to `img/g1`.

Just open it with a text editor.

If you want to name it, used `g1.render(filename='g1.dot')`.

Comment: My problem is now that the `g1.render(filename='g1.dot')` makes 2 outputs, so i would get a `g1.dot` and a `g1.dot.png`. Is it possible to make this `g1.dot` and `g1.png`?

Comment: you have to notice that `g1.view()` also produce source and image files.

Comment: the library is design that way : if source is named "f.x", image is named "f.x.png". I can't find any way to change it. But you can do it in python (module "os") or in shell.

Comment: I just added a one-line solve for my problem: this renames (or replaces) it how i want it to be. `move(os.path.join(path, "dotfile.dot.png"), os.path.join(path, "dotfile.png"))`